# Unlock iPhone 4 iOS 5.0.1 with baseband 4.11.08

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

I had a jailbroken unlocked iPhone with iOS 5.0, but by mistake I updated it to iOS 5.0.1 with iTunes. I'm asking this as both a cautionary tale to others as well in hopes that perhaps there is a jailbreak option I am overlooking.

In the process of the update from 5.0 to 5.0.1, the baseband was also updated to 4.11.08 and as expected, the phone became locked again as evidenced by the fact that it says "No Service" when I try to use my SIM.

Is there a way to unlock my iPhone 4 with iOS 5.0.1 other than asking the carrier to which it was initially locked?

Answer (score 4):

You can't. Not only is there no way to unlock the new baseband, but there's also no way to downgrade it. You are out of luck.

Comment: Can we make it to reinstall, to Factory setting so that all upgrade go away. Any Idea how long to wait to get it fixed by some thirdparty to get some solution.

Comment: **No.** There are no "factory settings." This is why the internet is plastered with notices *NOT TO UPDATE*. I'd bet money the site you got your unlock tool from probably said the same thing. And notices that once you do, you are SOL. There is no way of going back. I have absolutely no knowledge when the next unlock will be released. Head over to http://blog.iphone-dev.org/ for more details.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of carriers (in the UK) that allow you to unlock your phone after a contract is over. I know that I was able to unlock an iPhone on O2 as soon as the contract was up, I was able to do the same thing whilst the contract was still.. running on Vodafone.

Comment: how did you manage to unlock your o2 iphone 4?

Comment: In general, you ask them to perform the service and once they verify eligibility, it gets entered into the database that tracks these things and tells iTunes how to handle that phone when it gets activated after a restore.

Comment: If the contract is up, contact O2 and ask them to unlock it for you.

Answer (score 0):

By now it is possible to **down**-grade your baseband - at least for the iPhone 3G and 3GS (unfortunately not 4/S) - from the iPad's 06.15 to 05.13.04 (un-lockable) thanks to the great work of the iPhone Dev Team:

> The iPhone Dev Team is happy to announce a baseband downgrade option in redsn0w for those who are using the iPad’s 06.15 baseband on the iPhone3G or iPhone3GS.
>
> Typically you’d have the 06.15 baseband if you unlock with ultrasn0w but updated your iPhone baseband past 05.13.04.  With this new capability, you can now downgrade specifically from 06.15 to 05.13.04 (even if you never had 05.13.04 on that device before).  This gives you the best of both worlds: ultrasn0w compatibility and a normal iPhone baseband with full GPS and the ability to use stock IPSWs again.

See [this post](http://blog.iphone-dev.org/post/25350690843/0615-fun) on their blog.